# Split separated spatial objects into different files

Tags: r, gis, spatial

I have a number shapefiles. Some of these contain separated collections of counties, as the one below. For the data visualized, my goal is to split the shapefile into three separate files, where one contains the two counties on the left, one contains the single unit above, and the last on contains the remaining units.

Does anyone know a command which would help to do this?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here an example how you can go about it if you know which counties go into which group (i.e. not based on polygon characteristics).

```
library("raster")
library("rgdal")

swe <- getData('GADM', country='SWE', level=1)
group1 <- c("Gotland", "Halland","Kalmar")
swe1 <- swe[swe$NAME_1 %in% group1,]
plot(swe)
plot(swe1, add=TRUE, col="red")


writeOGR(swe1, dsn = "swe1", layer="swe1", "swe1",
         driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=T)
```

And so forth for the other groups.

For the large group it would of course be tedious to type or even copy-paste all the names. Instead you can do this:

```
group2 <- c("Orebro", "Blekinge","Dalarna")
swe2 <- swe[swe$NAME_1 %in% group2,]

'%ni%' <- Negate('%in%')
swe3 <- swe[swe$NAME_1 %ni% c(group1,group2),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try dbscan package, it will cluster counties the way you want. Use low `minPts`, 1 or 2, and experiment with a few `eps` values. Then collect each cluster and dump to a separate shape file.